# Grouping adjacent equal elements of a 2D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder if there is a function to group equal, connected elements of a 2D array like

```
a = np.array([[12,12,14,14,11,11],
              [10,10,11,11,11,11],
              [10,14,14,10,11,13],
              [12,12,14,13,13,13]])
```

into an array this:

```
            [[1, 1, 2 ,2, 3, 3],
             [4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3],
             [4, 5, 5, 6, 3 ,7],
             [8, 8, 5, 7, 7, 7]]
```

The rules for connection: an element [i, j] is connected to [i-1, j], [i+1, j], [i, j-1], and [i, j+1].

I found [scipy.ndimage.measurements.label](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.measurements.label.html) but the problem is that it just consider the array values as zero (background) and ones.

Comment: What's wrong with the first array? The elements are already "grouped".

Comment: @ReblochonMasque for example `12,12` in the first row is grouped as 1 but in the last row as 8

Comment: Then why is 10 in the second row in the same group as 10 in the 3rd?

Comment: this one was a mistake, edited the question.

Comment: Still a mistake: 2nd row: 10 maps to 4, 3rd row, 10 maps to 4, then maps to 6!

Comment: 11 is the same... please clarify exactly the rules of classification, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is where the "connection" comes in! 10 numbers that are "connected" to each other will have same group number. another 10 will have another group for itself because it has no connection in its surrounding.

Comment: connection can be defined in the 4 or 8 neighbouring cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the number of unique values, it may be practical to simply use `label` in a loop, adding the results with appropriate offsets. The offsets are needed because after, say, the first 3 features are labeled, the labels for subsequent ones should begin with 4, and so on.

```
from scipy.ndimage import label
values = np.unique(a.ravel())
offset = 0
result = np.zeros_like(a)
for v in values:
  labeled, num_features = label(a == v)
  result += labeled + offset*(labeled > 0)
  offset += num_features
print(result)
```

This prints

```
[[4 4 7 7 3 3]
 [1 1 3 3 3 3]
 [1 8 8 2 3 6]
 [5 5 8 6 6 6]]
```

which is the same as your expected result, up to permutation of labels (which don't have any meaning anyway).